# Getting crash while trying to get distinct row from core data swift 3 with predicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, distinct, predicate

I am trying to get array of distinct rows from core data and i am trying below code.

```
func fetchDataFromLocalDB() {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Session_Subjects")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dmode_id == %@", "\(User.deleveryMode)")

        request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
        request.propertiesToFetch = ["subject_id"]
        request.returnsDistinctResults = true
        request.predicate = predicate
        do{ 

// Here my app is crashing
            arrResultSubject = try managedContext.fetch(request) as! [Session_Subjects] 

        }
        catch  {
            // print(eror)
        }

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    //For data fetch in coredata

    let sectionIndex = IndexSet(integer: 0)
    self.tableSubjectView.reloadSections(sectionIndex, with: .automatic)

}
```

But i am getting crash when assigning value above [Session_Subjects] is array of coredata class.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually there are error messages associated with a crash, and those messages usually provide details of what went wrong. What messages did you get?

Comment: don't comment out your error handling code!
if there are any problems returning the data you will ALWAYS get a crash if you use as! - replace this with as? and you will be able to handle problems gracefully

Comment: getting this error "Could not cast value of type 'NSKnownKeysDictionary1' (0x10b6ceaf8) to 'projname.classname'"